# Copy/paste range from one worksheet to next available column in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I am trying to copy a range of data from one worksheet into another worksheet in the same workbook.

So copy range("A2:B10") in Sheet1 then paste in ("A2") in Sheet2.

Each time the macro is run, I would like the values in ("Sheet 1").Range("A2:B10") to be pasted in consecutive columns, so in the second run, in <s>"B2"</s> "C2" in Sheet 2.

I have the first part, but struggling with the 2nd part:

```
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()
'Set range
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B10").Copy  Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")
'Copy the data
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B10").Copy
'Activate the destination worksheet
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
'Select the target range
Range("A2").Select
'Paste in the target destination
ActiveSheet.Paste

Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Presumably you mean A2 and then C2 (not B2) as your range is two columns wide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something that will do the job without using `Active` and `Select`:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim ws1         As Worksheet
    Dim ws2         As Worksheet        
    Dim source      As Range
    Dim target      As Range        
    Dim lastColumn  As Long

    Set ws1 = Worksheets(1)
    Set ws2 = Worksheets(2)

    With ws2
        lastColumn = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(1)) > 0 Then
            lastColumn = lastColumn + 1
        End If
    End With

    Set source = ws1.Range("A2:A10")
    Set target = ws2.Cells(2, lastColumn)

    source.Copy destination:=target
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

The trickiest part in the code is to start writing on the correct column on the target worksheet. If the worksheet is empty, then the correct column is the first one. In every other case, the correct column is the last column + 1.

The standard way of finding last used column - `Range.End(xlToLeft).Column` would always return the first column as a last used column, w/o paying attention whether it is used or not. Thus you need some kind of a check, to know whether it is empty or not: `WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(1)) > 0`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Really appreciate it. Learned a lot from this.

Comment: Your comment about Range.End(xlToLeft).Column makes sense to me. 

Question for you in regards to pasting values, would I be able to use ".PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats" or ".Value" in any part of this script? I tried playing around with it, but can't seem to figure it out. Thanks again!

Comment: @P.Saha - you are welcome. Concerning the pasting of the values, probably the best way to learn a bit is simply to record a macro and see the code there. In my code remove the part `destination := target` and on the next line add `target.PasteSpecial Paste:= xlPasteFormats`, it should work. Glad I could help - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Used "target.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)" after struggling with the syntax and it worked.Thanks again! Very helpful and again helped me learn.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is odd

This line `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B10").Copy  Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")` is copying and pasting all in one line. So your subsequent lines where you `.copy` `.activate` `.select` and `.paste` are redundant. Your first line already did all of this.

You need to identify the last used column in Row "A" of Sheet2. To do this you can use the `.End()` method of a range to find the first occupied cell in the row. Then use that cell as your copy `Destination`:

```
 Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()

     'Declare a variable to hold the cell to which we will paste the data
     Dim pasteCell as Range

     'Set the variable to the first empty cell in Row 2
     Set pasteCell = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("IV2").end(xlToLeft).Offset(,1)

     'Copy and paste
     Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:B10").Copy  Destination:=pasteCell
End Sub
```

Comment: With this offset you would never fill out column A.

Comment: Do you really use Excel 2003 (judging from the IV column)? I am afraid to ask why, because I might know the reason...

Comment: You are right about that column A issue. I think the bigger takeaway is the `.End()` method, the redundant copy and pasting, the use of variables to handle dynamically determined things in VBA and the like. The `IV` is just my old school lizard brain writing code without thinking about nicer ways of doing it like `Columns.Count`. That being said, I do still know someone that has retained an XP laptop so they can use Access 2003 o_0

Comment: I am
 commenting the negative parts only ☺ Tester's mentality. I know some people supporting applications on 2003, thought you were one of them. Cheers ☺